# C program, strange behaviour

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Recently I came across the problem of geting 'Oops, Spwan error, can not allocate memory' while working with one C Application.

To understand the File Descriptor and Memory management better I give a try this sample program and it gives me shocking result.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[]);

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
int fd = 0;
unsigned long counter=0;
while (1)
{
char *aa = malloc(16384);
usleep(5);
fprintf(stderr,"Counter is %ld \n", counter);
fd = fopen("/dev/null",r")
}

return 0;
}
```

Here in the sample program I am trying to allocate memory every 5 micro second and also open a file descriptor at the same time.

Now when I run the program it started increasing the memory and also file descriptor star increasing, but memory increase upto 82.5% and file descriptor increase upto 1024. I know 'ulimit' set this parameter and it is 1024 by default.

But this program must crash by eating the memory or it should gives error ' Can't spawn child', but it is working.

So Just wanted to know why it is not crashing and why it is not giving child error as it reached file descriptor limit.

Comment: Always check return value!

Comment: Add a write to the memory that you allocated to the loop. You should see the difference. But be carefull, your system might really be difficult to access after some time.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but abbreviating `argc` and `argv` as `ac` and `av` makes your code harder to read with no compensating benefit. If you're not going to use them, just declare `int main(void)`.

Comment: This question is vague, non-constructive, has typos everywhere (particularly in `fd = fopen("/dev/null",r")` causing compiler errors), and relies upon implementation-defined behaviour with no mention of the implementation used (eg. gcc on Linux? Windows? ...).

Answer (score 2):

It's not crashing probably because when `malloc()` finds no more memory to allocate and return, it simply returns `NULL`. Likewise, `open()` also just returns a negative value. In other words, the cooperation of your OS and the standard library is smarter than it would enable your program to crash.

Comment: Linux will "overcommit" by default (that is, it will give you a virtual address back but not allocate any physical memory to back it until you try to write to it), so `malloc` returning `NULL` is not going to happen often. In *this* program, it will, eventually, happen of course, as the system will run out of virtual addresses sooner or later.

Comment: @NikBougalis Then the explanation changes to "you can't exhaust the memory by doing `while(1) malloc(1000000);`

Comment: If you have overcommit enabled, then you can't exhaust physical memory with that `while` loop - what you can exhaust is your own *virtual* memory.

Comment: I just wanted to create a problem which was facing by me before some days where A Program is eating memory and file descriptor is constantly increasing, after some value, it gives me error as 'Can't spwan Child'. So to replicate the big program I just give a try to the above program for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in doing that?

Plus on linux, the system won't even eat up the memory if nothing is actually written on "aa".

And anyway, if you could actually take all the memory (which will never happen, for Linux and *bsd, don't know about windows), it would just result in making the system lag like hell or even freeze, not just crashing your application.

Comment: You won't be able to freeze the system, but *if* you were that would mean there's a horrible bug with the Linux kernel.

Comment: That's what I'm saying basically. Maybe it's not clear enough, I'll rephrase.

Comment: That program keeps running well. Before some days I found a strange behaviour of one program where File descriptor fd keeps increasing in /proc/self/fd, I did search the problem and found that perhaps file descriptor has not closed properly, so to replicate the same behaviour I've written this program, but it keeps running.